# how to validate only http:// or https:// starting urls using python

Tags: python, url

My code:

```
import re
url=input("enter the url")
match_obj=re.match( r'^(?:http)s?://',url,re.I|re.M)
if match_obj:
    print("valid url",match_obj.group())
else:
    print("invalid url")
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Any constraint on what comes after http:// or https:// ?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with the code you showed, some example on how to use it and the expected output

Comment: in line 3 ?: should be eliminated and replaced with http|https

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

url=input("enter the url")
regex = re.compile(r'https?:\/\/([^\/]*)')
regObj = regex.findall(url)
if regObj :
    print("valid url")
else:
    print("invalid url")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of regex, you could just use [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
url = input('Enter the url: ').lower()

if url.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
    print('valid url')
else:
    print('invalid url')
```